# Counting dropped items after removing them from droppable area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to count dropped items inside dropped area. Here is [example](https://jsfiddle.net/97u0peju/171/). It works fine except one thing. when I start to remove items it does not count first item and only after removing first item number starts to decrease.

Function i am using to remove item:

```
$(".procStaff").on('click', '.closer', function(){
    var item = $(this).closest('.dropClass');
    var element = $("#myAccordion ul li").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == item.text(); 
    });

    //code where i counting items       
    var n = $(this).closest("div.proc").find(".dropClass").length;
    $(this).closest("div.proc").find("span.assigned").text("People Assigned: " + n + "");           

    itm.splice(item);
    element.css('color','black');
    item.fadeTo(200, 0, function(){ item.remove(); })
});
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one Line Update in  `$(".projLeader").on('click', '.closer', function(){});`

```
var n = $(this).closest("div.proc").find(".dropClass").length -1;
```

**Live Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/97u0peju/172/)

Answer (score 0):

It works now

https://jsfiddle.net/97u0peju/174/

```
$(".projLeader").on('click', '.closer', function() {
   var me = $(this);
   var item = $(this).closest('.item');
   var n = $(this).closest("div.proc").find(".dropClass").length;
   $(this).closest("div.proc").find("h6").text("Items Dropped: " + (n-1) + ".");
   itm.splice(item);
   item.fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
       item.remove();
   })
});
```

Since you are counting before removing the item, you should use `n-1` and not `n` while displaying because `n` will decrease after printing the count